# How to find path with filename

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

Im working on a program, that should make graphs based on json files. Most of the GUI is working and made with tkinter, i also know how to make graphs with matplotlib, the problem is finding the specific path for the files by clicking on them:

[image: Screenshot from app]
[image: with buttons]

I want the program to make the graph when i click on a specific filename.

I have tried os.path.dirname(), and i have also looked at filedialog with tkinter, but i cant seem to make it work. I have found a piece of code that makes a pop-up window, but i cant make it find where the file is placed on my pc.

```
def items_selected(event):
    # get selected indices
    selected_indices = vores_listebox.curselection()
    # get selected items
    selected_json = ",".join([vores_listebox.get(i) for i in selected_indices])

    msg = f'You selected: {selected_json}'  # besked i pop-up

    showinfo(title='Information', message=msg)  # Titel på pop-up



vores_listebox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', items_selected)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: How and where do you get those filenames? It is better to provide a [mre].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Im still pretty new to coding, so im sorry if i cant explain it clearly. I get the file names with the following code:

def vis_NS():
    vores_listebox.delete(0, END)
    # Husk at ændre mapper##
    for x in os.listdir("C://Users//canal//OneDrive//Dokumenter//AAU//3. semester//1"):
        if x.endswith(".json"):
            vores_listebox.insert(END, x)

Comment: Then you already have the required directory, so how come you cannot find the path?

Comment: Its because i get files from 4 different directories. I have 4 different tabs with that lists different files in the listbox, i have added a picture in the question

Comment: i made it work by  adding this line:
full_file_path = ":C//........" + selected_json

Answer (score 0):

You could store your filenames and their associated parent directories in a dictionary when you fetch them (before you populate the listbox)

```
file_dict = {  # example...
    '1D1.json': 'C:/parent/path/one/',
    '1D2.json': 'C:/parent/path/one/',
    '1D3.json': 'C:/parent/path/two/',
    '1D4.json': 'C:/parent/path/two/',
    '1D5.json': 'C:/parent/path/three/',
    '1D6.json': 'C:/parent/path/three/',
}
```

Then populate your listbox with the `keys` (filenames) from that dictionary

```
for index, filename in file_dict.keys():
    vores_listebox.insert(index, filename)
```

Then you can get the parent directory of a given file rather trivially by retrieving it from the dictionary

```
parent_dir = file_dict[vores_listebox.get()]
```

I'm not sure if you've configured the listbox to allow for multiple selections, but you'll likely want to handle that similarly by iterating over the selections.